# Calculating the progress percentage

Tags: c#

I am using webclient to dowlnoad a file. I am calculating the progress percentage as below

1. I know the filesize (I read it from the database table) of the file going to be downloaded.
2. I am depending on the `BytesRecieved` property of WebClient to know the total bytes fetched during download.
3. The algorithm I am using is `double dProgress = (e.BytesReceived / FileSize)*100);` to calculate the progress percentage.

However i am not getting correct progress percentage to update the progress bar.

Is there any method to calculate progress percentage?

Comment: sorry, i didnt get what u just told.

Comment: How do you know it's wrong? Is it always the same? 0? NaN? > 100? Negative? What is the exact problem?

Comment: What values *do* you get? When you check FileSize and e.BytesRecieves, are they actually the values you expect? What if you just output these values, maybe the numbers make more sense than a broken progressbar.

Comment: I am recieving 16384 as bytesRecieved and 4846266 as totalfilesize

Comment: I think I found the problem already (the result being 0 was a good hint). See my answer below.

Comment: This could be the server not behaving correctly.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Look at the following line:
`double dProgress = (e.BytesReceived / FileSize)*100)`

If both `e.BytesReceived` and `FileSize` are integers then you will always have `0 * 100 = 0`.

Make something like this:

`double dProgress = ((double)e.BytesReceived / FileSize)*100.0`

It is because `/` does integer division when dividing two integers. But you don't want that. So you convert one of the variables to `double`.

Comment: i used your code and found that the code is correctly generating. however the progress bar is filling only quarter. i am using the minimum as 1 and maximum as 100. the minimum step as 0.1 and maximum step as 1.0.any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for this notion :)

Answer (score 6):

BytesReceived and FileSize most probably are integers so you need to calculate progress this way:

```
double dProgress = 100.0 * e.BytesReceived / FileSize;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are handling the `DownloadProgressChanged` event when doing an asynchronous download, the event args already has a `ProgressPercentage` on it, so there is no point in re-inventing it. A contrived example:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var reset = new ManualResetEvent(false);
client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("{0} percent complete", e.ProgressPercentage);
client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => reset.Set();
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://myfilepathhere.com"), "file.name");
//Block till download completes
reset.WaitOne();
```

Comment: i am getting the e.Progresspercentage always as 0 so i am hunting for alternative methods

Comment: I notice the same thing, progress isn't reliable or using proper increments so I am adding kb/s labels and calculating % based on file size and bytes downloaded to get more accuracy. Not sure what it is currently doing?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that both numbers are integers. When you devide them, they become smaller than 1, so they round down to 0. Typecast them to make the result a float:

```
double dProgress = ((double)e.BytesReceived / FileSize)*100)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very tricky problem with basic arithmetic and casting in C#.

## Solution

First store the result of integer division in a double variable. And then type cast that to an integer.

```
int x = 5, y = 10, answer;
double ansDouble;
answer = (int)(x / y) * 100; //percentage calculation
Console.WriteLine("percentage={0}", answer);
//>output percentage=0

answer = (int)((double)x / y) * 100; //percentage calculation
Console.WriteLine("percentage={0}", answer);
//>output percentage=0

answer = (int)((double)x / (double)y) * 100; //percentage calculation
Console.WriteLine("x={0}", answer);
//>output percentage=0

answer = (int)(x/(double)y) * 100; //percentage calculation
Console.WriteLine("x={0}", answer);
//>output percentage=0

ansDouble = ((double)x / y) * 100;
answer = (int)ansDouble;
Console.WriteLine("percentage={0}", answer);
//>output percentage=50
```

## Points to note

Turns out that x/y = 0, for any values of x and y as long as they are integers
We can't solve this in one line by any casting combinations

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
```

...

```
  void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) {

            double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
            int percente = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
            progressBar.Value = percente;
        }
```

Or just using the `ProgressPercentage` value.

```
 void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
           progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; 
  }
```

Comment: I know I'm year and half late, but I have to respond to this. Is this **double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString())** trolling or you don't know what is type-casting?